# Objective-C ARC vs. MRR: why the switch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I am a new cocoa developer coming from a C#/Java background. I had been introduced to memory management patterns which objective-c language uses and I just find them very helpful for code-conscious development.

Why does Apple now want us to use [ARC](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/) (Automatic Reference Counting) instead of [MRR](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i) (Manual Retain-Release) and what advantages other than time saving does ARC offer?

I see such a transition negatively affecting good-citizen habits that developers gain from the obj-c ecosystem.

Nick

Comment: Thanks @pst for the the editing. That was my first post and I forgot to further explain new acronyms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's unfortunate that making it easier for competent developers to be correct has a side effect of making it easier for new developers to not learn, but it seems like it's probably worth it.

ARC *is* less forgiving than a tracing collector like C# or Java use though. If you don't have a clear object ownership model you will almost certainly create cycles and leak tons of memory. My hope would be that this is made obvious enough (via Instruments? That still requires seeking it out... not sure what could be done here) that new developers will quickly learn to keep their object graph clear and acyclic.

Comment: Thanks @Catfish_Man, I would rather prefer ARC being more like a compiler warning system supported by the static analyzer.

Comment: @NicholasE.Credli: It's strict on purpose: Most of the ARC rules are borne out of the principle that the compiler must be right 100% of the time, so when you throw it a case that's ambiguous, it will not guess what you mean but simply throw an error. The solution is simply to make your code unambiguous.

Answer (score 9):

ARC allows me to concentrate on writing useful code instead of boilerplate dealloc methods.

Most people I know have used `autorelease` behind every `alloc` anyway, because it saved you a `release` later and you couldn't forget to actually put it. So the object was around until the autorelease pool was drained, and with ARC the object gets deallocated when it isn't needed anymore. I think in those cases the ARC-compiled program will even use less memory.

And, *shame on me*, it helps me to make my apps crashing less often too.
That premature release that happens every 10.000 launches. The one that I could never track down completely, hopefully with ARC this is a thing of the past.

---

> I see such a transition negatively affecting good-citizen habits that developers gain from the obj-c ecosystem.

probably in the same way an embedded developer who started with assembler thinks people that start with C and have never used assembler get into bad habits.

In my opinion the MRR vs ARC discussion is similar.
ARC and C both allow to write more maintainable code in a shorter time. 
And both of them can lead to a larger memory and cpu footprint.
If I remember correctly Apple announced that they did add a little speed up to `retain` and `release` to compensate that impact on cpu usage. And because of that there is no real reason that MMR is still around.

I, for one, welcome our new ARC overlords.

Answer (score 2):

i've actually rather enjoyed moving to ARC - it's one less thing to think about. on top of that, i think newcomers would often be tripped up by the significance of naming conventions (+alloc, -copy etc vs [NSString stringWith....]). the only tricky bit is when you start dealing with CoreFoundation etc (the C APIs) where you still have to keep in mind just who is owning what.